# deleting and reusing a temp table in a stored precedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to SELECT INTO a temp table multiple times with a loop but I just can't do it, because after the table created by SELECT INTO you can't simply drop the table at the end of the loop, because you can't delete a table and create it again in the same batch.

so how can I delete a table in a stored procedure and create it again? 
is it possible to this without using a temp table?

here is a snippet of where I am actually using the temp table which is supposed to be  a pivoting algorithm:

```
WHILE @offset<@NumDays BEGIN
    SELECT 
    bg.*, j.ID, j.time, j.Status
    INTO #TEMP1
    FROM #TEMP2 AS bg
    left outer join PersonSchedule j on bg.PersonID = j.PersonID and
    j.TimeSlotDateTime = @StartDate + @offset

    DROP TABLE #TEMP2;
    SELECT * INTO #TEMP2 FROM #TEMP1 
    DROP TABLE #TEMP1

    SET @offset = @offset + 1
END
```

Comment: Because table structure is going to change with each iteration.

Comment: Hopefully CTEs will do what you need. If not I can think of quite a horrible way involving dynamic SQL and global temporary tables named after NEWID().

Comment: How is `#TEMP2` defined prior to the first loop iteration?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008, you are allowed to drop and recreate tables in a loop in a stored procedure:

```
create procedure CreateTablesInALoop
as
declare @i int
set @i = 0
while @i < 100
    begin
    select 1 as id into #t
    drop table #t
    set @i = @i + 1
    print 'Yay'
    end
go
exec CreateTablesInALoop
go
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm currently using sql server 2005 :(.

Comment: strange is that it executes on 2005 as well

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do with the temp table?

One option is to use table variable, not temporary table.

Or you can try using [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) like this:

```
  WHILE @offset<@NumDays  
   BEGIN
        WITH tmp1 AS (SELECT 
        bg.*, j.ID, j.time, j.Status
        FROM #TEMP2 AS bg
        left outer join PersonSchedule j on bg.PersonID = j.PersonID and
        bg.TimeSlotDateTime = j.TimeSlotDateTime and
        j.TimeSlotDateTime = @StartDate + @offset
    )

SELECT * FROM tmp1 

    SET @offset = @offset + 1
END
```

Comment: I had to use the temp table because they could be automatically created with the right schema by SELECT INTO, because the table didn't have a fixed schema I couldn't use a table variable.(in each iteration of the loop new columns is added to temp table)
Common Table Expressions might be the solution, I will try it;).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I wanted to point out why the original posters script threw an error, while the sample answer provided did not.

In the OP's example although he did a DROP TABLE, he also did 2 separate SELECT into commands.  While the suggested solution did only 1 SELECT INTO (in a loop).  The OP's procedure failed on Compilation.  The compiler saw two attempts to create the same table, while in the suggested solution the compiler only saw 1 attempt to create the table therefore it allowed the procedure to be created.